# MySQL >> Custom Site Search on comma-separated tags w/o many-to-many table

Tags: mysql, search, tags, wildcard, sql-like

I have developed a content portal of educational resources and I need to offer users a custom search tool.

All resources live in the Resources table. The table contains a field called "RES_Tags" that contains a comma-separated list of tags (keywords) for that resource.

An example of the data in the RES_Tags field for a Resource about the environment might be "environment, nature, Earth, global warming, climate change, pollution, oceans, forests, rainforest, mining, deforestation".

I need a SQL search query strategy that will allow a user to enter a search string and get records whose tags match in spirit (ie. not necessarily identical).

So, for example:

- a user searching for "ocean" should get all records with the tag
  "ocean" in the RES_Tags field.
- a user searching for "ocean" should get all records with the tag of the plural "oceans".
- a user searching for "ocean" should get all records with tags that include the word "ocean" such as ("ocean fishing", "Pacific ocean", or "ocean acidification")
- a user searching for "ocean acidification" should get all records
  with the tag "ocean" or the tag "acidification" or the tag "ocean
  acidification".
- a user searching for "ocean" should NOT get any records with "ocean" embedded  in the tag ("interocean", "suboceans", "oceanic", etc.), except for the plural "oceans". While it looks like it would make sense in this case, we wouldn't want the search term "art" to return records because they have the tag "Jimmy Carter"
- it would be AWESOME and MAGICAL (but not at all necessary) if a search for "ocean" returned records with tags related to oceans like "seas", "water", "marine", etc.

The query needs to include an understanding of commas, so that a search for "ocean, sea life, seas" returns records with the tags "ocean", "seas" and "sea life".

The query also needs to include an understanding of quotes, so that a search for "sea life" (in quotes) only returns records with the tag "sea life" and not records with only "sea" or "life".

So far, this is the solution I am using:

```
    IF InStr(1,Request.Form("SearchString")," AND ",1) > 0  OR InStr(1,Request.Form("SearchString")," OR ",1) > 0 THEN

        IF InStr(1,Request.Form("SearchString")," OR ",1) > 0 THEN
        searchArray_4 = Split(Request.Form("SearchString"),"OR",-1,1)
        FOR EACH x IN searchArray_4
            'Response.Write("OR split: "& x)
            strHRE_SqlStr_WHERE = strHRE_SqlStr_WHERE & "RES_Tags LIKE '%"& Trim(x) &"%' OR "
        NEXT

        strHRE_SqlStr_WHERE = strHRE_SqlStr_WHERE & ") OR "
        strHRE_SqlStr_WHERE = strHRE_SqlStr_WHERE & "("
        END IF
        IF InStr(1,Request.Form("SearchString")," AND ",1) > 0 THEN
        searchArray_5 = Split(Request.Form("SearchString"),"AND",-1,1)
        FOR EACH x IN searchArray_5
            'Response.Write("AND split: "& x)
            strHRE_SqlStr_WHERE = strHRE_SqlStr_WHERE & "RES_Tags LIKE '%"& Trim(x) &"%' AND "
        NEXT
        END IF
    ELSE
        searchArray_1 = "%"& Request.Form("SearchString") &"%"
        strHRE_SqlStr_WHERE = strHRE_SqlStr_WHERE & "RES_Tags LIKE '"& searchArray_1 &"' OR "

        strHRE_SqlStr_WHERE = strHRE_SqlStr_WHERE & ") OR "
        strHRE_SqlStr_WHERE = strHRE_SqlStr_WHERE & "("

        searchArray_2 = Split(Request.Form("SearchString"))
        FOR EACH x IN searchArray_2
            strHRE_SqlStr_WHERE = strHRE_SqlStr_WHERE & "RES_Tags LIKE '%"& Trim(x) &"%' OR "
        NEXT

        strHRE_SqlStr_WHERE = strHRE_SqlStr_WHERE & ") OR "
        strHRE_SqlStr_WHERE = strHRE_SqlStr_WHERE & "("

        searchArray_3 = Split(Request.Form("SearchString"),",")
        FOR EACH x IN searchArray_3
            strHRE_SqlStr_WHERE = strHRE_SqlStr_WHERE & "RES_Tags LIKE '%"& Trim(x) &"%' OR "
        NEXT

    END IF
```

I am sure this approach is an amateurish hack and I would be very grateful to see if there are better solutions out there.

BTW, there is a similar question here ([php/mysql: Custom site search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811666/php-mysql-custom-site-search)) that I've read and I would like to use a solution that doesn't involve normalizing the RES_Tags field (if possible). So, I'm writing this as a different question. Hope that's ok.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for in this question? Does your query works but you're looking for review? Are you stuck at a specific part? Once you split the string, I'd look here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Comment: I'm looking for a SQL Query that will satisfy the conditions. I haven't been able to figure it out with LIKE and wildcards. I did get close, so I've shared my example. I guess I'd like to avoid a solution too dependent on REGEX b/c I will be getting searches with accented characters and I have heard that can be problematic.